# How add In-App Purchases for iOS from Info.plist

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

How In App Purchases are look like in Info.plist? It's a tricky question from the part of "how to enable IAP for iOS by not having Xcode editor, and macOS itself".

While the most questions and answers are going in a direction:

- Xcode's Capabilities panel to turn on In-App Purchases
- select the IDs to use

What's the outcome from those UI actions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apple Pay and merchant IDs are nothing to do with in app purchase.  Apple Pay is used to bill for real world goods and services (like a pizza delivery as an example)

Comment: Updated the text, but it was given as an example of UI changes, where as I'm interested in the code change for IAP.

Comment: There are no changes to the info.plist for in app purchase.  Adding the in-app purchase capability in Xcode simply adds the StoreKit framework to your project's dependencies.

Comment: I'm interested in the changes. that are happened with the project after activating IAP.

Comment: The StoreKit framework is added to the target's linked frameworks. That is all.

Comment: It's not answering "what's changed in the sources" by added StoreKit framework

Comment: Nothing is changed in the source code when you add in app purchase capability in Xcode. You need to write code to use StoreKit. If you are asking how to write code to implement in app purchase, then that question is too broad for stack overflow. There are many articles on the web and you can watch Apple WWDC videos and read Apple documentation

Comment: It cannot be so... at least SKStoreProductParameterOfferID, CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS. So, I would like to take an answer from someone who've noticed the change, or can try it on macOS.

Comment: I tried it on a Mac. I added the In app purchase capability and observed the changes tracked against git - The project file changed to include the Store Kit framework.  In fact I have multiple apps in the store that have in-app purchases and I haven't even added the in-app purchase capability to them. IAP works.

Comment: May you share a `kdiff` or `git diff` of "the project file changed to include the Store Kit framework"? That was my initial question.

Comment: That probably wouldn't be helpful because pbxproj files are not something that you can modify outside of Xcode and as I said, I have apps with working in app purchase and I haven't added StoreKit or the in app capability Xcode project.

Comment: Not actually so, I've been patching pbxproj as a text file for signing purposes (by not having macOS). Right now I've faced with a rejection of IAP (from TestFlight they've been working): "We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review."

Comment: That means you have IAP products in App Store Connect that haven't been submitted for review.  This is nothing to do with your code or your Xcode project. You need to submit the product for review in App Store Connect.